# "Helper Table" in my Dataset? Need assistance with best approach

Tags: c#, linq, datatable, dataset, helper

Hopefully, this one is short and easy.  I'm writing something c# and I've reached a spot where  the wheel has been invented a million times over, but I'm not sure which one to use. First, the rules:

1. There are CharacterClasses and there are Skills
2. Each of these has a DataTable in the DataSet loaded from CSV
3. Each CharacterClass consists of multiple skills
4. Each Skill may be present in multiple CharacterClasses

My choices seem to be:

A. Create a field that is a list of CharacterClassIDs within each skill.  That will get nasty big and makes it hard to edit my CharacterClasses for balance later.  I'd need to iterate through the list in order to create Characters or edit them.

B. Create a field in CharacterClasses that houses a list of SkillIDs.   That would make updating skills difficult to balance, and again, will lead to a huge blob field. Again, I'd also have to iterate through a list, but this time it'd be the one created when I CONTAINS query the Skills table for the CCID field.

C. Create a helper table at runtime, which holds SkillIDs and CharacterClassIDs as matches, but how?

C seems the wisest from a design standpoint, but I'm not sure how to get there.  DB Design has always been a stumbling point for me.  My brain is dealing with coder's block and I can't quite get my head wrapped around how to create the Helper table that contains CharacterClassIDs and SkillIDs without creating a third config file (which I don't want to do).   Any input?  Am I going about this all wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a relation therefore you should use a proper relational database. I'd look into SQLite for such a simple task.